# Without solving the equation, show that all nine roots of $( − 1)^{10} = ^{10}$ lie on the line $Re () = \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

**Problem**: Without solving the equation, show that all nine roots of $( − 1)^{10} = ^{10}$ lie on the line $Re() = \frac{1}{2}$.

I would like to say I tried something but I am actually clueless. I was thinking maybe I could use De Moivre's theorem but I am not sure how.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take absolute values on both sides. You get
$$
|z^{10}|=|(z-1)^{10}|\\
|z|^{10}=|z-1|^{10}
$$
Since absolute values are non-negative reals, we can take the tenth root without fear and get
$$
|z|=|z-1|
$$
Which is to say, the distance from $z$ to $0$ is equal to the distance from $z$ to $1$.